# Flutter Error:Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user: Flutter Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have just started mobile app development and I choose flutter as my first mobile app developing language(I know python,html,javascript already). I have installed flutter and all the dependencies that flutter doctor told me i needed, but when i proceed with creating a new project It shows this weird error.

```
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user
```

I have downloaded flutter in my documents folder and that is where my project is as well. Can someone help me out with this, it would be very much appreciated.

In case you needed it, here is the the flutter doctor-v result

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1440], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at C:\Users\Hassan\OneDrive\Documents\flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (12 days ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Hassan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Edge (web) • edge • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 85.0.564.67
```

Comment: It seems strange to put Flutter under documents. Could you try installing it at c:\flutter ?

Comment: sure i will try it

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
$ sudo xattr -c -r  <project_folder>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to uncheck read-only attribute in property of that particular folder and then you will have write permission and then it will work.

For example,in my case,It was as below

[image]